# Determine if the direction of travel is north or south based on bearing

Tags: direction, bearing

I have some data where bearing has been calculated using latitude and longitude of the current and previous data point. How would I figure out which direction of travel I am going using this bearing?

I have taken the python implementation from here (the response with 6 upvotes):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54873868/python-calculate-bearing-between-two-lat-long

The results I get range from -180 to 180. I have tried understanding how these mean direction of travel is North or South, but have had no luck.

The expected output would be "North" or "South"

Comment: What did you call bearing, how was it exactly calculated ?

Comment: Please add example points and what you would expect as a result

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. While certainly geographic in nature, this Question is not GIS-centric.

Comment: Hi Apologies, I have added in a couple of comments now

Comment: What happens if you stick points in there? Say you test with lat=52 and lon=9 as first point and lat=53 and lon=9 as second point. The bearing in this case is due north. What ìs your algorithm output? Then try again with different point combinations bearing((52,9),(52,10)) is due east, bearing((52,9),(53,10)) is northeast etc.. Look what numbers you get and see if you can figure out their meaning.